# ng-file-upload for image upload not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to upload an image using `ng-file-upload` in AngularJS, but it is not happening properly, as file-related properties like size and name are all showing undefined. My code is given below:

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="reviewForm" role="form" ng-controller="reviewController" ng-submit="reviewSubmit()" novalidate>    
...    
    <input type="file" id="image" ngf-select ng-model="reviewer.image" name="image" ngf-pattern="image/*" accept="image/*" >
...
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('carApp', ['ngResource', 'ngFileUpload'])
.controller('reviewController', ['$scope', 'updateReviews', 'Upload', function($scope, updateReviews, Upload) {

$scope.reviewSubmit = function() {
    alert($scope.reviewer.image.lastModifiedDate);
        Upload.upload({
            url: 'images',
            method: 'POST',
            data: { file: $scope.reviewer.image, number: 10 }
        }).progress(function(event) {
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * event.loaded / event.total);
            console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + event.config.data.file.name);
        }).success(function(response) {
            console.log('Success ' + response.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + response.data);
        }).error(function(error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error.message);
        });

        ...
```

When I am checking the object type (i.e. `alert($scope.reviewer.image)`), it shows `[object File]`, but when  try to print the name and size etc...it always shows `undefined`. Please help!! I have to access the image file properly in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try as shown below.This is just a working version of image uploader.Please change the properties as you wish.

This is the working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/0ausn68h/2/)

***Html***

```
<body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Upload on form submit</legend>
      <br>Photo:
      <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="file"    
             accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required
             ngf-model-invalid="errorFile">
       <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.maxSize">File too large 
          {{errorFile.size / 1000000|number:1}}MB: max 2M</i>
      <img ng-show="myForm.file.$valid" ngf-thumbnail="picFile" class="thumb"> 
      <br>
      <button ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" 
              ng-click="uploadPic(picFile)">Submit</button>
      <span class="progress" ng-show="picFile.progress >= 0">
        <div style="width:{{picFile.progress}}%" 
            ng-bind="picFile.progress + '%'"></div>
      </span>
      <span ng-show="picFile.result">Upload Successful</span>
      <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
  </form>
</body>
```

***JS***

```
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
    file.upload = Upload.upload({
      url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
      data: {username: $scope.username, file: file},
    });

    file.upload.then(function (response) {
      $timeout(function () {
        file.result = response.data;
      });
    }, function (response) {
      if (response.status > 0)
        $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
    }, function (evt) {
      file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
    });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Its not working in safari+win-7. Please check your demo.

Comment: @satya please create an issue here : https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues

Comment: @ Samapth : i am facing same problem and already reported.check this https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/1672 but there is no solution came yet.